# cronjob timing - for every 3 months

Tags: shell-script, cron

I chanced upon this example:

```
0 9 1-7 * 1 *                       First Monday of each month, at 9a.m.
```

1. I am not sure the `1-7` portion which is supposingly to be the dates of each month.  Why is it a `1-7` instead of a `*`?
2. How do I write a cronjob that run every 3 months at 0000hrs?

   ```
   0 0 1 */3 * *
   ```

Is the above correct?

Comment: Note that the example you show is wrong. The 1-7 is supposed to restrict it to the 1st week, and in combination with the 1 to indicate Monday it should mean it only runs on the 1st Monday. HOWEVER: if both day-of-week and day-of-month are specified, then the job runs whenever ONE of those is true; this is documented in the manpage for the crontab file format (at least on Debian). So the example would run EVERY Monday, and the entire whole 1st week of every month.

Comment: @wurtel in that case, how do i make it run on the 1st monday of every month only ?

Comment: This is how `mdadm` does it in its crontab on Debian: `57 0 * * 0 root if [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi` i.e. select (in this case) Sunday, then check with an `if` statement whether the day-of-month is less than or equal to 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
#* * * * * command to be executed
#- - - - -
#| | | | |
#| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
#| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
#| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
#| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
#------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Yours is correct. After five astreisks, there must be a shell command.

You can confirm the cron tab is running or not, by doing `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`. For testing purposes, you can use `n` minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`0 9 1-7 * *` runs the job once per day (at 9:00), but only on the first 7 days of the month. That's one way to run a job on the first Monday of the month: run it on the first 7 days, but don't do anything unless that day is a Monday.

```
0 9 1-7 * *  if [ "$(date +%u)" = 1 ]; then do_stuff; fi
```

`0 9 * 1 *` runs the job every Monday. That's another way to run a job on the first Monday of the month: run it every Monday, but don't do anything unless it's within the first 7 days of the month.

```
0 9 * * 1  if [ "$(date +%_d)" -le 7 ]; then do_stuff; fi
```

`0 9 1-7 * 1 *` looks like some kind of failed attempt to combine these two methods. Note that `0 9 1-7 * 1` runs the job every Monday *and* every day for the first 7 days of the month.

As for `0 0 1 */3 *` (you put an extra `*` at the end), it runs a job on the first of each month at midnight, but only if the month is a multiple of 3. That is indeed executed every three months.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there's a big difference between "*3rd month*" and "*every 3 months*".
The first one refers to each 3 months starting from first month of the year. For instance, taking 2021-11-01 00:00:00 as starter point, we have:

- next at 2021-04-01 00:00:00
- then at 2021-07-01 00:00:00
- then at 2021-10-01 00:00:00
- then at 2021-01-01 00:00:00

To accomplish that, the syntax should be `0 0 1 */3 * *` as you suggest. Check this out [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*/3_*)

The another one is pointing to 3 months taking into account the current one. For example, if we have 2021-11-01 00:00:00 as starter point, we have:

- next at 2022-02-01 00:00:00
- then at 2022-05-01 00:00:00
- then at 2022-8-01 00:00:00
- then at 2022-11-01 00:00:00

To accomplish that, the syntax is `0 0 1 2-12/3 * *` as you suggest. You can check this out [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_2-12/3_*).

> Notice that you must count the number of "*each month you want*" in
> the future, and start the range from this number to the last one of
> the year (the month 12). In the previous case, the starting month was
> month 11 (November), if we count 3 months in the future, we are going
> to get month 2 (February of the next year).